# How to fit long strings in a table (Latex)?

Tags: latex

i need to create a table having 4 columns and 2 rows.

Any helps?

I tried whit this code but it doesn't fit well all the words

```
\begin{table}[tbh]
    \centering{\scriptsize
        \begin{tabular}{p{0.2\textwidth}p{0.2\textwidth}p{0.2\textwidth}p{0.4\textwidth}}
        \toprule
        \textbf{Name}& \centering\textbf{Description} &\centering\textbf{Type of data}&\centering\textbf{Source}
        Continuum Geologico della Regione Toscana & Geologic database of Tuscany Region. Scale  1:10000 & Vector data Esri Shapefile& Tuscany Region Council http://www.regione.toscana.it/-/banche-dati-cartografiageologica\\ \hline
        DEM& Digital elevation  model. Cell size 10 meters& Raster float & Tuscany Region Council http://www.regione.toscana.it/ \\ \hline
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Any helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- the narrower the page, the harder it will be to fit the table into it. If you are allowed to modify the page layout, load e.g. the `geometry` package to make the margins a bit smaller
- the syntax `\centering{...}` is wrong, it is a switch and does not take an argument. Remove the `{}`
- A table with narrow columns and long words usually looks better left aligned than justified
- don't set urls as normal text, they can contain letters that will make your document crash. Instead you should use the `\url` macro from `hyperref` or `url` package. To enable more line breaks in your table, I also recommend the `xurl` package
- your code was missing some `\\` and if you already use the `booktabs`, there is no good reason to still use `\hline`. Using a `\midrule` will give you better spacing around it.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[tbh]
    \centering
    \scriptsize
    \begin{tabular}{@{}P{0.18\textwidth}P{0.20\textwidth}P{0.12\textwidth}P{0.4\textwidth}@{}}
        \toprule
      \textbf{Name} & 
        \textbf{Description} &
            \textbf{Type of data}&
                \textbf{Source}\\
      \midrule
      Continuum Geologico della Regione Toscana & 
        Geologic database of Tuscany Region. Scale  1:10000 & 
            Vector data Esri Shapefile& 
                Tuscany Region Council \url{http://www.regione.toscana.it/-/banche-dati-cartografiageologica}\\
        \addlinespace
      DEM& 
        Digital elevation  model. Cell size 10 meters& 
            Raster float & 
                Tuscany Region Council \url{http://www.regione.toscana.it/} \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: really thanks @user36296. Clear and useful explanation!!!

Comment: @Elisam You're welcome!